# DomException: not a valid selector //button[contains(., 'buttonText')] when executing js script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this HTML item:

```
<button id="toolbar-item-17-update-id" type="submit" name="action" value="update" class="button-action-update btn btn-secondary">
        Edit
    </button>
```

And I use this path to get it `//button[contains(., 'Edit')]`. With this syntax I can find the button when inspecting element, but when I use this syntax in javascript I get DOMException: not a valid selector.

What is the correct syntax that I should be passing here?

```
let btn = document.querySelector("[contains(., 'Edit')]");
```

Comment: _"What is the correct syntax..."_ - a valid CSS selector (as it is mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for `.querySelector()`: _"...This string must be a valid CSS selector string; if it isn't, a `SyntaxError` exception is thrown..."_). Your example is an XPath.

Comment: What is the css selector equivalent of my xpath?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: how about sending me a link that solves my problem instead?

Comment: My comment is a link. And that link is clear in its meaning. And it will also solve your problem.

Comment: There is already an ID for your element: just select it by ID, i.e. `document.querySelector('#toolbar-item-17-update-id')`. It has the highest specificity and the quickest method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let note = document.querySelector('.button-action-update');
```